# apache HttpClient, form-based login, and retrieve HTML content

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I want to use apache HttpClient api to login into a website: rfp.ca and retrieve its html content, followed is my code.

After I ran it, it only returned the source code of the login page: http://www.rfp.ca/login/
which still asks for the credentials and I was expecting it to be redirected to http://www.rfp.ca/my_account/ just like login using the browser.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;



public class HttpGetter {



        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.rfp.ca/login/");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
            System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
            List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://www.rfp.ca/login/");

            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "myusername"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "mypassword"));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

            System.out.println("Response "+response.toString());
            entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String str ="";
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(""+str);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();        

    }
}
```

here is the returned results:

```
    Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Initial set of cookies:
- [version: 0][name: PHPSESSID][value: f4dc36acc705b31b15b4ea07a398a60b][domain: www.rfp.ca][path: /][expiry: null]
Response HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date: Sat, 17 Mar 2012 04:04:49 GMT, Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635, X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17, Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT, Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, Pragma: no-cache, Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent, Connection: close, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8]
Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">

  <head>

<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=utf-8"/>     

<title>RFP.ca: User login form</title>

<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/_system/main/images/css/form.css" />

<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/design.css" />


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rfp.ca/system/lib/rating/style.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.rfp.ca/system/ext/jquery/css/jquery-ui.css"  />

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rfp.ca/system/ext/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rfp.ca/system/ext/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rfp.ca/system/ext/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>






<style type="text/css">

*html img,

*html.png

{

  azimuth: expression(

    this.pngSet?

      this.pngSet=true : 

        (this.nodeName == "IMG" ? 

          (this.src.toLowerCase().indexOf('.png')>-1 ? 

            (this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none", this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.src + "', sizingMethod='image')",

                this.src = "http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/blank.gif") :

            '') :          

          (this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.toLowerCase().indexOf('.png')>-1) ?

            (this.origBg = (this.origBg) ? 

              this.origBg :             

              this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.toString().replace('url("','').replace('")',''),

              this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.origBg + "', sizingMethod='crop')",

              this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none") :

            ''

        ), this.pngSet=true

  );

}

</style>



<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-254707-12']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

    </head>

<body>

<div id="messageBox"></div>

<div class="MainDiv">
    <div class="headerPage">
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="png"></div>
            <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/"><img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/logo.png" border="0" alt="" title="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="userMenu">
                            <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/" title="RFP Home"> Home</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt="" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
                <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/find_rfps/" title="Search">Search</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt="" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
                <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/rfp_alerts/?action=new" title="E-mail Alert">E-mail Alert</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt="" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
                <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/contact/" title="Contact">Contact</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt="" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
                <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/login/" title="Sign In"> Sign In</a>
                        <br/><br/>
<!--            
            <form id="langSwitcherForm" method="get" action="">
                <select name="lang" onchange="location.href='http://www.rfp.ca/login/?lang='+this.value+'&amp;'" style="width: 200px;">
                                            <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
                                            <option value="tr">T√ºrk√ße</option>
                                            <option value="ps">Ÿæ⁄öÿ™Ÿà</option>
                                            <option value="fr">Fran√ßais</option>
                                            <option value="ar">ÿßŸÑÿπÿ±ÿ®Ÿäÿ©</option>
                                            <option value="en" selected="selected">English</option>
                                            <option value="fa">ŸÅÿßÿ±ÿ≥€å</option>
                                            <option value="ja">Êó•Êú¨Ë™û</option>
                                            <option value="es">Espa√±ol</option>
                                            <option value="nl">Nederlands</option>
                                            <option value="ru">–†—É—Å—Å–∫–∏–π</option>
                                            <option value="pt">Portugu√™s</option>
                                    </select>
            </form>
-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"><br /></div>

<div class="indexDiv"   >







    <h1>Sign In</h1>


    <p style="color:#9B9B9B"><i>Tip: Username is your e-mail address</i></p>

    <form action="http://www.rfp.ca/login/" method="post" id="loginForm" >

        <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="" />

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />


        <fieldset>

            <div class="inputName">Username</div>

            <div class="inputField"><input type="text" class="logInNameInput" name="username" /></div>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>

            <div class="inputName">Password</div>

            <div class="inputField"><input class="logInPassInput2" type="password" name="password" /></div>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>

            <div class="inputName">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="inputField"><input type="checkbox" name="keep" /> Keep me signed in</div>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>

            <div class="inputName">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="inputField"><input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" /></div>

        </fieldset>

    </form>

    <br/>

    <a  href="http://www.rfp.ca/password_recovery/">Forgot Your Password?</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/registration/">Subscription</a>



</div>

<div id="grayBgBanner"></div>

    <div class="clr"><br /></div>
    <div class="bottomMenu">
        <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/">Home</a> <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt="">
        <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/faq/"> About Us/FAQ</a> <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt=""> 
        <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/features/"> Features</a> <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt=""> 
        <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/contact/" >Contact</a>  <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt="">
        <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/privacy_policy/">Privacy Policy</a> <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt="">         
        <a href="http://www.rfp.ca/terms_of_use/">Terms of use</a> <img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt=""> 
        &nbsp;&copy; 2012 Organized Media &nbsp;<img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/sepDot.png" border="0" alt="">    
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/rfpca" rel="me" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/twitter.gif" border="0" alt="Twitter"></a><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/RFPca/164233376967738" rel="me" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.rfp.ca/templates/rfp/main/images/facebook.gif" border="0" alt="Facebook"></a>       
        </div>
</div>
<div class="Footer">
</div>
</body>

</html>

Post logon cookies:
- [version: 0][name: PHPSESSID][value: f4dc36acc705b31b15b4ea07a398a60b][domain: www.rfp.ca][path: /][expiry: null]
```

I tried adding these two parameters:

```
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("return_url", "http://www.rfp.ca/my_account/"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "login"));
```

and it turned out some error:

```
Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Initial set of cookies:
- [version: 0][name: PHPSESSID][value: e76f3b507a3db64cf1d4ad2297fb0c58][domain: www.rfp.ca][path: /][expiry: null]
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:822)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at Crawler.HttpGetter.main(HttpGetter.java:203)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid redirect URI: ?Ûiÿü0Â·éq¯æÉ§¢éí
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.createLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:116)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getRedirect(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:193)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.handleResponse(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1035)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:492)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 0: ?Ûiÿü0Â·éq¯æÉ§¢éí
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3066)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3024)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.createLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:183)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but from what I can see in the form, it would expect the following parameters

```
return_url:
action:login
username:myusername
password:mypassword
```

And you do not provide the first two in the `POST` request.

UPDATE: The best way to get the right parameters in such a case is, open the URL in browser and then monitor the network activity in Firebug or Developer Tools (WebKit). It will show you exactly what you need to send programmatically.

Comment: thanks for your reply, this time I added these two parameters: nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("return_url", "http://www.rfp.ca/my_account/"));
         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "login")); and it returned some error

Comment: I found the solution, 
instead of using the actual url : 

    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("return_url", "http://www.rfp.ca/my_account/"));

I left the parameter value blank like this:

    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("return_url", ""));

and the web server just deals with the redirect.

Cheers
Eric

Comment: @EricSRK : You didn't need to specify the return_url in the first place, it DOES expect a blank value. Hence my answer had no value for it. Glad you solved it! :) You seem to be new to StackOverflow. Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you. Marking an answer keeps your accept ratio healthy and helps others to find out the answer to the asked question quickly.

Comment: Hi how would i submit the dialog "would like to access your public profile and friend list".

Comment: @jackyesind I have no idea what you're talking about. Please open a new question! Someone might be able to help you if you elaborate!