# Apache HttpClient, form-based login, Doesn´t retrieve HTML content

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Httpclient from apache to access another page behind form-based login authentication, but, I am receiving the same form-based login page as a result.

Should I do somenthing different?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/salvaurls/");

    // Request parameters and other properties.
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("return_url", "http://localhost/salvaurls/painel.php")); 
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "http://localhost/salvaurls/autenticacao.php?acao=login"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "desenvolvimento@gmail.com.br"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senha", "123"));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity_ = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, Consts.UTF_8);
    httppost.setEntity(entity_);

    //Execute and get the response.
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {
        try (InputStream is = entity.getContent()) {
            System.out.println("entrou");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String str ="";
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(""+str);
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

index.html - login form that is displayed after run the code:

```html
<body id="LoginForm">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="form-heading">login Form</h1>
        <div class="login-form">
            <div class="main-div">
                <div class="panel">
                    <h2>Salva URLs</h2>
                    <p>Please enter your email and password</p>
                </div>
                <form id="Login" action="autenticacao.php?acao=login" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="login" name="login"
                            placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha"
                            placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="forgot">
                        <a href="reset.html">Forgot password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you please share the code of the form your are trying to access? This maybe could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747198/apache-httpclient-form-based-login-and-retrieve-html-content/9747378

Comment: I found an error in my code. I changed from: params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "http://localhost/autenticacao.php?acao=login")); to: params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "http://localhost/salvaurls/autenticacao.php?acao=login")); but it still not working.

Comment: @NickAth, I followed this question, and I reproduced without success.

Comment: Could be any number of reasons. I have a similar system where I have to read the login page and send the cookies returned from that initial call with the login request otherwise I am redirected back to the login page.

Comment: `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/salvaurls/autenticacao.php?acao=login");`

Comment: @mnesarco, I changed as you said but now, I am not receiving nothing as a return.

Comment: Now your are posting to the correct URL, the result depends totally on the php application you are posting to. So it is impossible to determine what is happening based on the information you have provided.

Comment: @JohnMendes did you try to debug the php function responsible for the login that you are accessing through the http client? Does it seem to get hitted? what it does?

Comment: @NickAth I have a redirection in my autentication.php. I don´t know if it is stopping access the painel.php that is behind the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the login url at all. Change the HttpPost url to `http://localhost/salvaurls/autenticacao.php?acao=login` and remove the action parameter from the list.

```java
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/salvaurls/autenticacao.php?acao=login");

// Request parameters and other properties.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("return_url", "http://localhost/salvaurls/painel.php"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "desenvolvimento@gmail.com.br"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senha", "123"));
```

Normally the server sends a cookie if you had authenticated successfully. For further requests you may need a cookie store.

```java
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/salvaurls/autenticacao.php?acao=login");

// Request parameters and other properties.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("return_url", "http://localhost/salvaurls/painel.php"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "desenvolvimento@gmail.com.br"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senha", "123"));
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity_ = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, Consts.UTF_8);
httppost.setEntity(entity_);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost, context);
String response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

If you are doing further authenticated requests you need to use the HttpClientContext with the cookie store every time. Hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe the Server requires some more request attributes, e.g. referrer or user agent. Therefore you have to debug your browser request and copy all attributes to your request.